# filtering returned data based on another set of data in knockout foreach loop

Tags: c#, knockout.js, foreach

so i have two sets of foreach loops in which i am using to display two sets of data. The first list show a list of users based on an id and the other list shows more users based on another id. The first list of users are also found within the second list of users.

I want to know is there a way that i could display my second list of users but show only users that are not already in the first list of users? So if in my first list i have: John, Jack, Jane. My second list currently is: John, Jack, Jane, Kim, Matt, Tom. I would like my second list to show only: Kim, Matt, Tom.

Here are my foreachs:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Users">
  .....
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: FullUsers">
  ......
</div>
```

Both **Users** and **FullUsers** are `ko.observableArray([]);` and using the same viewModel.
How can display my results for **FullUsers** and not showing users that already exist in **Users**?

possible computed results to display:

```
this._FilteredUsers = ko.computed(function(){
     var _list = this.AddFullUsers(); //all users (this.AddUsers) is list of certain users
     if(_list() > 0){
         return ko.utils.arrayFilter( _list(), function(item){
          return something here that will return the filtered list of users that are not in this.AddUsers 
     });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that either a) the contents of `Users` and `FullUsers` are primitive types (e.g. strings) or b) they're objects and if the same user is in both lists, they're both references to the same object, then you could use

```
this._FilteredUsers=ko.computed(function() {
  var self=this;
  return ko.utils.ArrayFilter(self.FullUsers(), function(item) {
    return ko.utils.ArrayIndexOf(self.Users(), item)<0;
  });
}, this);
```

Comment: when i tried this i got the same three users and not the full list without the three. So my users: Adam, Angie, Sam and the full users: Adam, Angie, Sam, Tom, Jill. My filteredUsers was still just Adam, Angie, Sam

Comment: Are you sure you copied the second `return` statement exactly? The result you're getting is what you'd get if the condition was `>=0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways. 2 off the top of my head:

When creating the arrays, if an object is already in Users don't put it in users
Have a bool function which returns whether a FullUser is a member of Users and bind Visibility to that result (well, the NOT of the result).

Any other way your imagination can supply....

Comment: I was wonder if i could created a computed function but i am not sure how to go about doing it?

Comment: Well, writing a js function in your ViewModel would be one way of creating a computed function. What do you mean by a "computed function"?

Comment: I added to my original post what i had in mind regarding a computed function/statement. That will check/filter and return list of users that are not in the other list.

Comment: i don't know how to properly write my return statement :)

Comment: You need to think very carefully about what you want to achieve, and what steps you need to take to achieve it. In this case, for each entry in FullUsers, you want to go through Users and if the FullUser is not in Users you add it it to the FilteredUsers list. Make a start with that and see how you go.